# Strange behaviour: Same code, different errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, tensorflow, development-environment

I have to use packages tensorflow and pygame.

In my machine [Ubuntu 15.04][Anaconda, Python=2.7] I installed
pygame and tensorflow in the same environment.

Now, when I import tensorflow in the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import tensorflow
```

it works fine. If I go into the interpreter via `/usr/bin/python`

and do `>>> import tensorflow` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

On top of this, every time in the `/usr/bin/python`,

Upon running a program I get:

```
>>> execfile("deep_q_network.py")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "deep_q_network.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

and In running the same program in `python` interpreter, I get:

```
>>> execfile("deep_q_network.py")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "deep_q_network.py", line 8, in <module>
    import wrapped_flappy_bird as game
  File "game/wrapped_flappy_bird.py", line 19, in <module>
    IMAGES, SOUNDS, HITMASKS = flappy_bird_utils.load()
  File "game/flappy_bird_utils.py", line 21, in load
    pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/0.png').convert_alpha(),
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file
```

It seems in anyway my code is failing despite hours spent on installing and fixing those installs.

Please help if this could be resolved.

---

`pip show tensorflow` gives:

```
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.9.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
Installer: pip
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/v/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy, six, protobuf, wheel
Classifiers:
  Development Status :: 4 - Beta
  Intended Audience :: Developers
  Intended Audience :: Education
  Intended Audience :: Science/Research
  License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Mathematics
  Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
  Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries
Entry-points:
  [console_scripts]
  tensorboard = tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard:main
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Anaconda in the correct way?

```
$ conda install virtualenv
$ conda create --name=tensorflow_env python=2.7
$ source activate tensorflow_env
$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Maybe, you also have installed it in the wrong directory.
Try to run:
`pip show tensorflow` and make sure it's in the right path.

Comment: Unfortunately, couldn't find any directory issues.

Answer (score 0):

try `$ sudo pip install tensorflow`